# Is it possible to disable roaming entirely, not just networking during roaming?

Tags: settings, roaming

When trying to google the solution to this I mostly just find instructions on how to disable data connections during roaming.

To clarify why I'm asking, I have a contract with a small local phone company and they have a roaming contract with a large local provider. When roaming on the large providers network I get calls at the same rate, but no 3G network. My phone seems to quite frequently choose to go roaming even in areas where the home network gets full strength signal.

Is it possible to stop an android phone from connecting to roaming networks?

Comment: What happens if you go into Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> System select and choose "Home only"?

Comment: Can you tell us your motivation in doing this?

Comment: "System select" is not an option under Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks on my phone. The options are "Data enabled", "Data roaming", "Access point names", "Use only 2G networks" and "Network operators". Under "Network operators" there are options to choose a specific network, but the phone eventually goes roaming even if I've chosen the home network there.

Answer (score 5):

Just go to flight mode <s>or remove the SIM card when you are on roaming.</s>

Comment: Note that some phones won't let you boot without a SIM card.

Comment: Another solution: Shut the phone off :P

Comment: @Bruce: yeah true. maybe just use  the flight mode

Answer (score 2):

I expect an app like Tasker or Locale could do this.

There look to be some apps that can do this for you. A quick perusal of the AppBrain market found this:

- [HTC 911 Roaming Assistant](http://www.appbrain.com/app/htc-911-roaming-assistant/com.apchernykh.htcroamingassistant)